# Issue with using Substring within SQL

Tags: mysql, substring

I am facing a problem coming up with a SQL query for a certain issue:

Table 1

```
Client ID|Name of Client|Customer Type|Account Type|

01| A |    AB        |      30      |
02| B |    AB        |      30      |
03| C |    CD        |      30      |
04| D |    CF        |      40      |
```

Table 2

```
Argument|Switch|

AB30     |  Y  |
CD30     |  N  |
CF40     |  Y  |
```

Table 3

```
ClientID|Name Of Client|External_Information|

01|A    | External A
02|B    | External B
03|C    | External C
```

Currently, I am trying to extract the information based on 3 different tables. I am suppose to extract the External Information  from Table 3 based on 3 conditions

1. The Client ID must exist in Table 3 and Table 1
2. If the Client ID exist in Table 3 and Table 1, then we must check in Table 2 if the combination of `Customer Type` and `Account Type` (eg : For Client ID 01 , the combination would be `AB30`)
   in Table 1 exist in Table 2 and if the `Switch` in Table 2  = "Y".

My current SQL would be :

```
select External_Information 
from Table_3 a 
where a.ClientID = (select ClientID 
                    from Table_1 
                    where ClientID = a.ClientID)
```

This would solve Condition 1 , but for condition 2 I am not sure how we are able to do it within the same SQL query.

The expected result should be :

```
External_Information
-----------------------
External A
External B
```

Comment: your table 2 doesn't have foreign key in either table 1 or table3 add table1_id or table3_id first on your table 2

Comment: Your table 3 is missing a column heading.

Comment: Sorry , I have corrected the issue with table 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN`s, and use `CONCAT()` to combine the two columns in Table 1.

```
SELECT a.`External_Information`
FROM Table_3 AS a
JOIN Table_1 AS b ON a.`ClientID` = b.`Client ID`
JOIN Table_2 AS c ON CONCAT(b.`Customer Type`, b.`Account Type`) = c.Argument
WHERE c.Switch = 'Y'
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d32da/1)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. The CONCAT statements works for me.